# I need to use a Formula in a cell that is part of a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

This gets complicated really fast because of the way I referenced the cells for my formula.  The ranges first, second, third, and forth reference a dynamic cell location.  here is the code I'm having trouble with.

```
Dim first As Range
Dim second As Range
Dim third As Range
Dim fourth As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long

For i = 0 To -170
For k = 0 To 170

    Set first = ws.Rows(3 + k).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0 + i, -12)
    Set second = ws.Rows(3 + k).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0 + i, -11)
    Set third = ws.Rows(3 + k).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0 + i, -8)
    Set forth = ws.Rows(3 + k).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0 + i, -7)

ws.Rows(3 + k).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -6).Formula = "=IF(OR(AND(first<(third-0.33),first<>0,first<1.33),AND(second<(forth-0.33),second<>0,second<1.33)),TRUE,FALSE)"

Next k
Next i
```

It doesn't come up with any errors and runs, but the formula is nowhere to be found on the worksheet.  It is designed to run my formula for each line of my data. It puts a value of true or false in a column that I specify.  Can anyone see if I did anything wrong? Thanks.

here is the file.  the macro is assigned to the button on the `Capability Report` worksheet.  the name of the macro is button_click 7.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Cnpvgoos3cTzQ4dVRpMHJ1Zjg

The macros won't run because it references my drive, but at least you will be able to look at the report.

Edit: This is the new code.  Refer to comments below to see what happened.

```
Dim first As Range
Dim second As Range
Dim third As Range
Dim fourth As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long

For i = 0 To 167

    Set first = ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0 + i, -12)
    Set second = ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0 + i, -11)
    Set third = ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0 + i, -8)
    Set forth = ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0 + i, -7)

ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -6).Formula = "=IF(OR(AND(" & first.Address & "<(" & third.Address & "-0.33)," & first.Address & "<>0," & first.Address & "<1.33),AND(" & second.Address & "<(" & forth.Address & "-0.33)," & second.Address & "<>0," & second.Address & "<1.33)),TRUE,FALSE)"

Next i
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on your `IF` formula. Does it work if you add that to the end?

Comment: @AlexisOlson no luck same issues

Comment: Have you checked that the formula works if manually entered in a cell?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I was using this formula for a long time before this.  Instead of words I use cell references example: `"BQ3"`.  I would just change the cell to the correct location in the past, but I'm trying to change it so that it's automated via button.  The formula is correct. whether the references are correct is another thing.

Comment: Try using `"=IF(OR(AND(" & first.Address & "<(" & third.Address & "-0.33)," & first.Address & "<>0," & first.Address & "<1.33),AND(" & second.Address & "<(" & fourth.Address & "-0.33)," & second.Address & "<>0," & second.Address & "<1.33)),TRUE,FALSE)"` - the ranges you create in your VBA code won't be available to Excel, so you need to pass them as addresses.  (I also corrected the spelling of `fourth`)

Comment: @YowE3K Would `ordinal.Value` also work?

Comment: You could also simplify that a lot by using RC notation - e.g. first.Address is just referring to `RC-6` so your formula would become ws.Rows(3 + k).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -6).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(AND(RC-6<( ....`

Comment: @AlexisOlson still no luck

Comment: @AlexisOlson - you could possibly embed the value, but then you have to worry about the conversion of the value to a string, which sometimes could become problematic.

Comment: Correction - first.Address would become `RC[-6]` not just `RC-6`

Comment: `ws.Rows(3 + k).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -6).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(AND(RC[-6]<(RC[-2]-0.33),RC[-6]<>0,RC[-6]<1.33),AND(RC[-5]<(RC[-1]-0.33),RC[-5]<>0,RC[-5]<1.33)),TRUE,FALSE)‌​"`

Comment: @AlexisOlson I'm afraid that hasn't worked either.  When talking to a friend about it, he mentioned that excel might not be able to run `i = 0 To -170` , but would have to change it  to `i = -170 To 0` .  he seemed to think excel wasn't smart enough to count backwards.  I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Ok so I got it to paste the formulas all the way up the column in the right location, but now it only references the cells in the last row. I'll post an edit with my new code.

Comment: @AlexisOlson see my answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have it figured out.  Off of my last update, the `first` code needed and `.Address` code to make the word first a location and not text.  The other problem I had was that My Formulas involving `i` were wrong.  Here is an updated code.

```
Dim first As Range
Dim second As Range
Dim third As Range
Dim fourth As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long

For i = 0 To 167

    Set first = ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -12)
    Set second = ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -11)
    Set third = ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -8)
    Set forth = ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -7)

ws.Rows(169 - i).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -6).Formula = "=IF(OR(AND(" & first.Address & "<(" & third.Address & "-0.33)," & first.Address & "<>0," & first.Address & "<1.33),AND(" & second.Address & "<(" & forth.Address & "-0.33)," & second.Address & "<>0," & second.Address & "<1.33)),TRUE,FALSE)"

Next i
```